# The rubymine in OSX can't attach to a rdebug-ide started session

Tags: ruby, macos, debugging, rubymine

The superficies problem is: rubymine can run ruby program, but can't debug them, neither remote debug, I got:

```
>> DIALOG: Connecting to debugger using 10 seconds
```

After a period about 10 seconds

```
>> DIALOG: Cannot connect to the debugged process at port 57000 [a random port]
>>>         Dumping and destroying...
>>>         Error Output: 
>>>         Fast Debugger(ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base19 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:57000
>> Please try increase timeout settings...(a long bullshit)
```

I try to find the root cause by reading ruby-debug-ide and ruby-debug-base19 code, found:

1. ruby-debug-ide has started a DebugThread(@control_thread) which will start a TCPServer bind on 127.0.0.1 and listen on port 57000.
2. ruby-debug-ide is waiting a client connect to the tcp server and send him a 'start' command to `run_prog_script`
3. I can `telnet 127.0.0.1 57000`, then the Debug Thread said: Connected from 127.0.0.1 ...
   If I puts a word 'start\n' in telnet, the rdebug-ide will start my real program.
4. Rubymine hasn't connect to it and send a 'start' command. (because I haven't find any output in the idea.log)

I dig into idea.log:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on   127.0.0.1:59598
at org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerProxy.a(RubyDebuggerProxy.java:647)
at org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerProxy.d(RubyDebuggerProxy.java:619)
at org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerProxy.getCommandSocket(RubyDebuggerProxy.java:381)
at org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerProxy.b(RubyDebuggerProxy.java:151)
at org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerProxy.attach(RubyDebuggerProxy.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.ruby.ruby.debugger.impl.RubyDebugProcess.attachToProxy(RubyDebugProcess.java:190)
```

Then I read debug-commons code(not accurate as rubymine, I refer to https://github.com/ruby-debug/debug-commons-java/blob/master/src/org/rubyforge/debugcommons/RubyDebuggerProxy.java

```
private Socket attach() throws RubyDebuggerException {
  int port = debugTarget.getPort();
  String host = debugTarget.getHost();
  Socket socket = null;
  for (int tryCount = (timeout*2), i = 0; i < tryCount && socket == null; i++) {
    try {
          socket = new Socket(host, port);
          ...
    }
  }
}
```

It seems rubymine can't use the debug-commons lib to open a socket connection at localhost, I can't dig more :(

BTW, Even we start a ruby debug session in shell by command below:

rdebug-ide --port 51202 -- path/to/my/script

rubymine can't connect to the socket also.

**Don't tell me I should use another ruby-debug-xxx gem or remove some other gems like ruby-debug, I'v tried those solutions. **

I'v tried with below groups:

Group1:

- rubymine 4.0.3
- ruby-debug-base19-0.11.29
- ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16

Group2:

- rubymine 4.5.x
- ruby-debug-base19-0.11.30.pre10
- ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14

my laptop is mac air with OSX Lion

Comment: Firewall blocks connection? Proxy configured in RubyMine? Try to see what happens with `tcpdump`/`wireshark`.

Comment: Do you have Computer name specified in System Preferences | Sharing?

Comment: I have a computer name as "air", but it can't be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I tried all of the suggestions (remove ruby-debug, line cache etc.) and none of them worked.  In my case, my macbook's hostname was set to localhost. I changed my hostname `sudo scutil --set HostName newHostName` and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I should use remote debugger instead of local debug.

First, compare local debug error:

```
Error:

  Cannot connect to the debugged process at port 57000 [a random port]

  Dumping and destroying...

  Error Output: 
  Fast Debugger(ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base19 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:57000

  Please try increase timeout settings...(a long bullshit)
```

with the debug-commons-java'code:

```
private void failWithInfo(ConnectException e) throws RubyDebuggerException {
    String info = debugTarget.isRemote()
            ? "[Remote Process at " + debugTarget.getHost() + ':' + debugTarget.getPort() + "]"
            : Util.dumpAndDestroyProcess(debugTarget);
    throw new RubyDebuggerException("Cannot connect to the debugged process at port "
            + debugTarget.getPort() + " in " + timeout + "s:\n\n" + info, e);
}
```

I can't see any debugTarget.getHost() in above error outputs, but it will tell me host if we debug remotely.

So I write a simplest ruby script(test.rb):

```
i = 10
begin
  puts "echo ok #{i}"
  i += 1
  sleep 1
end until i > 600
```

Then start a remote debug session in Ruby mine by default configurations:

- Remote host: localhost
- Remote port: 1234
- Remote root folder: path/to/test
- Local  port: 26201
- Local root folder: path/to/test

I found rubymine show exception as:

```
Error:

  Cannot connect to debugged process at port 54321 in 10s:

  [Remote Process at **localhost**:54321]
```

Then I change the remote host as "127.0.0.1", done!

So I guess that Rubymine will try to connect to debug target using "localhost" as host name, but it failed!

I try to find where the debugTarget's host is initialized, I got those code in debug commons RubyDebuggerFactory:

```
private static RubyDebuggerProxy startDebugger(final Descriptor desc, final List<String> args, final int timeout)
        throws IOException, RubyDebuggerException {

   ...
    // 127.0.0.1 seemingly works with all systems and with IPv6 as well.
    // "localhost" and InetAddress.getLocalHost() have problems on some systems.
    // cf. http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=143273 for one case
    RubyDebugTarget target = new RubyDebugTarget(proxy, "127.0.0.1", desc.getPort(),
            pb.start(), desc.getDebuggeePath(), desc.getBaseDirectory());
    proxy.setDebugTarget(target);
    RubyDebuggerProxy.PROXIES.add(proxy);
    return proxy;
}
```

Decompile rubymine.jar for org.rubyforge.debugcommons.RubyDebuggerFactory, though it's mixed, but we can find:

```
    RubyDebugTarget rubydebugtarget = new RubyDebugTarget(rubydebuggerproxy, "127.0.0.1", descriptor.getPort(), processbuilder.start(), descriptor.getDebuggeePath(), descriptor.getBaseDirectory());
```

I think rubymine connect to 127.0.0.1 but without permission enough, so i try to start ruby mine by follow command:

sudo /Applications/Rubymine.app/Contents/MacOSX/rubymine

But it still failed, so it's a bug of rubymine, if you have such a bad experience like me, use remote debugger to avoid it.

Thanks for remind about computer name from [Dennis Ushakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491092/dennis-ushakov)

Comment: My conclusion is: Rubymine set debugTarget as 'localhost' when I launch debugger for local script, which override the '127.0.0.1' in debug commons hard code.